# Solution Explanation, A club consists of $6$ freshmen, $7$ sophomores, and $8$ juniors. How many committees of $5$ people from all classes?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The answer was given to me by my professor without a very good explanation so I am still very confused. Doesn't help that I am still very confused about the leap from permutation to combinations. Our textbook is a brief edition designed for the quarter system and I feel like it does a very poor job of explaining these things and I am missing some things.

The answer being:  ${21\choose5} - {13\choose5} - {14\choose5} - {15\choose5} + {6\choose5} + {7\choose5} +{8\choose5}$

${21\choose5}$ being all the committees of $5$ people from this group of people

the ${13\choose5}, {14\choose5}$ and ${15\choose5}$ being the committees of people from the combination of two of the three groups of people such as freshman($6$) $+$ sophomores($7$) = $13$

The adding in of the committees of $5$ from just one group is apparently because they were reduced twice. I don't really understand this.

Is there a smaller concrete example that can be visualized showing how permutation and combination differs and help me understand this stuff?
I know it's the difference between ordered and unordered selection but I don't really intuitively understand combinations.

Comment: If we are looking at selecting 3 individuals to put in a car from a group of 5 candidates, and we don't care about the seating, this is a case of counting combinations. Example, we pick Abby, Bob, and Charlie from the group of 5, this is one combination out of the 5C3 total combinations. Bob, Abby, and Charlie being picked corresponds to the same combination, we would not count this a second time because we counted it already - the order being different does not qualify it as a distinct combination. [continued next comment]

Comment: If we instead consider the seating as important, say driver's seat is marked seat 1, etc., then having Abby in seat 1, Bob in seat 2, etc. is a *different* arrangement then Bob in seat 1, Abby in seat 2, etc. This is a permutation. These arrangements would qualify as permutations because the ordering of the selected candidates also matters (in addition to which candidates were selected). IMO, best way to getter better at distinguishing is to do many practice problems from the textbook.

Comment: Since you have a brief edition textbook I would recommend A First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross, amazing entry level textbook with tons of problems and solutions in the back to check your work

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to have a clear understanding of the principle of inclusion exclusion.

This particular problem fits exactly into the [three circle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) Venn Diagram case very clearly explained  and diagrammatically visualised in the link

So far as your query on permutations and combinations

- Each permutation represents a particular order, eg $ABC$ is different from $BAC$ or $CAB$ etc
- In a combination, the order of selection doesn't matter, as in a committee of equals, $ABC$ is the same as $BAC$, etc.

### Added

And to give you an alternative method, you know that you can choose at most $3$ from each type, and you need $5$ in the committee, so just find the coefficient of $x^5$ in

$\small(^6C_1x+^6C_2x^2+^6C_3x^3)(^7C_1x+^7C_2x^2+^7C_3x^3)(^8C_1x+^8C_2x^2+^8C_3x^3)$

the $x^k$ indicating the numbers chosen from each category. These are known as generating functions which you may not yet have been taught, but the idea should fairly clear; multiplying the three terms *adds* the exponents representing how many of each type are chosen

Comment: I think shifting the focus to the general case of Inclusion-Exclusion principle and generating functions is not that helpful for someone who is struggling with distinguishing combinations vs. permutations.

Comment: @Alborz:OP's  first query was "The adding in of the committees of 5 from just one group is apparently because they were reduced twice. I don't really understand this." That relates squarely to inclusion-exclusion.